# R Shiny - Resetting shinyTree node selections

Tags: r, shiny, shinytree

The app below contains a `shinyTree`, a reset button (`Reset nodes`) and a print output 'Selected nodes'. The print output prints the output of the `get_selected` function, which returns a list of selected nodes.

Here is a screenshot of the tree on start-up:

[image]

No nodes are selected so `get_selected` returns an empty `list()`

When I make a selection, e.g. node `a`, the `get_selected` correctly returns that selection:

[image]

When I click `Reset nodes`, the node selections are cleared in the tree UI but `get_selected` does not change from the previous selection:

[image]

When the reset button is clicked, an observer updates the tree via `updateTree` as follows:

```
observeEvent(input$reset, {

    updateTree(session,"tree", data = tree)
  })
```

I would like `get_selected` to return `list()` when I hit reset. Am I using `updateTree` incorrectly?

Here is the code to reproduce the above:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTree)

tree = structure(list(a=list(a1=1,a2=2) , b="b"), stopened = T) 

tree = lapply(tree, function(x) structure(x, stopened = T))

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script('
                        $("#reset").onlick(function() {
                        $("#tree").jstree("deselect_all");
                        }
                        ')),
  fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        actionButton('reset', 'Reset nodes')
      ),
      mainPanel(
        shinyTree("tree", ),
        hr(),
        "Selected nodes:",
        verbatimTextOutput("idSelected")#,
      )
    )
  )
)

# server

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$tree = renderTree({

    tree

  })


  output$idSelected <- renderPrint({
    str(get_selected(input$tree, format = "classid"))
  })


  # An observer is used to trigger a tree update when reset is clicked.
  observeEvent(input$reset, {

    updateTree(session,"tree", data = tree)

    print(get_selected(input$tree, format = "classid"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've tried the following JQuery to no avail:

```
$("#reset").onlick(function() {
                        $("#tree").jstree("deselect_all");
                        }
```

Comment: By now [PR 89](https://github.com/shinyTree/shinyTree/pull/89) provides us with the possibilty of setting `options(shinyTree.refresh = TRUE)` to get the desired behaviour - Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58517834/9841389)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could update a `reactiveVal` on hitting the reset button instead of directly referring to the data provided by `get_selected`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTree)

tree <- lapply(structure(list(a=list(a1=1,a2=2) , b="b"), stopened = TRUE) , function(x) structure(x, stopened = TRUE))

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        actionButton('reset', 'Reset nodes')
      ),
      mainPanel(
        shinyTree("tree", ),
        hr(),
        "Selected nodes:",
        verbatimTextOutput("idSelected")#,
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  treeSelection <- reactiveVal(list())

  output$tree = renderTree({
    tree
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    updateTree(session, "tree", data = tree)
    treeSelection(list())
  })

  observeEvent(input$tree, {
    treeSelection(get_selected(input$tree, format = "classid"))
  })

  output$idSelected <- renderPrint({
    treeSelection()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you @ismirsehregal! Would you know why `get_selected` wasn't changing? Was I using `updateTree` incorrectly?

Comment: You were using `updateTree` correctly. I'm not really familiar with `library(shinyTree)` but it seems updating/re-rendering the tree doesn't trigger an update for the selected nodes by design.

Comment: shinyTree contributor here: people generally don't want a callback when update tree is called because they already know what is in the tree. Certainly, input$tree would not be updated immediately after updateTree was called; you would still need to get the new input$tree in an observe.  The answer by @ismirsehregal is an elegant solution to your particular problem