# Save and restore selections in a shinyTree

Tags: save, selection, shinytree

Is it possible to save and restore selections of a shinyTree?

I found a solution deleting the selections
[R Shiny - Updating shinyTree node selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56555281/r-shiny-updating-shinytree-node-selections)

but I need to save the selections and restore them later for example, by an actionButton

Comment: Currently there is no way of doing that purely in R. You would have to dig in the JavaScript parts of `jsTree` to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with `shinyTree` only. Some functions of the underlying `jsTree` library have to be called directly and the values passed from JavaScript to R and vice-versa.

I made a small example, which should help you as a starting point.

If you save a selection via button-click, R sends a custom message to JavaScript, which will get the selected IDs and returns it to R via `Shiny.setInputValue`.

The selected ID's are then saved in the reactiveValues `selectionRV`, but you could save them in a file or database if needed.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTree)
library(shinyjs)

js <- HTML("
$(document).on('shiny:connected', function(event) {
  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('saveselection', function(e) {
    var selection = $('#tree').jstree().get_selected();
    Shiny.setInputValue('treeselection', selection, {priority: 'event'});
  });
})
")

## ui ####################
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(tags$script(js)),
  actionButton("deselect", "Deselect all"),
  actionButton("savesele", "Save Selection"),
  actionButton("restoresele", "Restore Selection"),
  shinyTree("tree", dragAndDrop = TRUE,types= #Types is in the same format that jstree expects
              "{
          '#': { 'max_children' : 2, 'max_depth' : 4, 'valid_children' : ['root'] },
          'root' : { 'valid_children' : ['file'] },
          'default' : { 'valid_children' : ['default','file'] },
          'file' : { 'icon' : 'fa fa-file', 'valid_children' : [] }
        }"
  )  
)

## server ####################
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  treeData <- reactive({
    rootstrc <- structure(list(
      SubListA = structure(list(
        leaf1 = structure("",sttype="file",sticon="fa fa-signal"), 
        leaf2 = structure("",sttype="file",sticon="fa fa-signal"),
        leaf3 = structure("",sttype="file",sticon="fa fa-signal")),
        sttype="root",stopened=F,sticon="fa fa-signal"
      ),
      SubListB = structure(list(
        leafA = structure("",sttype="default",sticon="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"),
        leafB = structure("",sttype="default",sticon="shinyTree/icon.png"),
        leafC = structure("",sttype="default",sticon="fa fa-signal")
      ),stopened=F,sttype="root",sticon="fa fa-signal")
    ),
    sttype="root",stopened=F,sticon="fa fa-signal"
    )

    list(
      root1 = rootstrc,
      root2 = rootstrc,
      root3 = rootstrc,
      root4 = rootstrc
    )
  })
  output$tree <- renderTree({
    treeData()
  })

  selectionRV <- reactiveValues(list = NULL)
  observeEvent(input$deselect, {
    runjs("$('#tree').jstree().deselect_all()")
  })
  observeEvent(input$savesele, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("saveselection", message)
  })
  observeEvent(input$restoresele, {
    req(input$treeselection)
    tmp <- paste0("[", paste(input$treeselection, collapse = ","), "]")
    js <- sprintf("$('#tree').jstree().select_node(%s)", tmp)
    runjs(js)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```